# Are marriages on yom tov recognized if all other halacha is observed?

Tags: marriage, yom-tov, pregnancy-birth

I attended a reform Jewish wedding on Shavuot and was wondering if the marriage is acknowledged and what the status of the children of that union are?

Comment: user2325, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for your interesting question. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site. Note though that the wedding you attended may very well not have observed all the other halachos of a wedding and may not be valid anyway. And, in any event, children born to unmarried people are for most purposes perfectly valid (not _mamzerim_, bastards, anyway).

Comment: Are you asking if the marriage is valid qua Shavuot or qua reform?

Comment: In my answer I assume the former, as it is the more unique question (and certainly less controversial!).

Comment: First or second day (assuming you're in the diaspora)?  Reform doesn't hold by yom tov sheni, so the second day is a regular day in the reform community.

Answer (score 10):

Shulchan Aruch [OC 339:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49625&st=&pgnum=371) rules that one should not perform Kiddushin (betrothal) or Nissuin (marriage) on Shabbat or Yom Tov. However he notes that if one did so, even on purpose, it works and the couple is fully married.