# Are marriages on Shabbat allowed?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, marriage

I saw [a similar question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16798), hope I'm not being redundant.

I wanted to know if marriages on Shabbat are allowed, and if not, where is it said, and why not.
Thanks in advance! It is a pleasure!

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16798/759

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Shulchan Aruch [OC 339:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49625&st=&pgnum=371) rules that one should not perform Kiddushin (betrothal) or Nissuin (marriage) on Shabbat or Yom Tov. However he notes that if one did so, even on purpose, it works and the couple is fully married.

The prohibition originates in the Mishna ([Beitza 5:2](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%94_%D7%94_%D7%91)). The Babylonian Talmud ([36b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=8&daf=36b&format=text) per Tosfot) explains that this is a rabbinic prohibition because marriage resembles a business transaction which is prohibited on Shabbat.